# Which is good approach for finding Item - multiple property in an object or array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Which function is better to find an item via `getDoneDataOne` or `getDoneDataTwo`?  Both method are calculated and created an array or object via Reduce (these logic not included)

For example `getDoneDataOne()` multiple property of ProductId's :

```
function getDoneDataOne() {
    return { 
        '111': { Name: 'Item One', TotalDone: 3 },
        '222': { Name: 'Item Two', TotalDone: 3 },
        '333': { Name: 'Item Three', TotalDone: 1 } 
    }
}
```

For example `getDoneDataTwo()` - return array of objects :

```
function getDoneDataTwo() {
    return [
        { ProductId: 111, Name: 'Item One', TotalDone: 3 },
        { ProductId: 222, Name: 'Item Two', TotalDone: 3 },
        { ProductId: 333, Name: 'Item Three', TotalDone: 1 } 
    ]
}
```

Which return format is preferred for searching Item?

It loop through `Batch` object and find an Item via `doneData`:

Option 1:

Is this correct implementation to find a item?

```
const doneDataOne = getDoneDataOne();
Batch.Products.forEach(batchProduct => {
    batchProductId = batchProduct.ProductId;

    if (doneDataOne[batchProductId]) { //Is this correct way?
        console.log(doneDataOne[batchProductId]);
    }
});
```

Option 2:

```
const doneDataTwo = getDoneDataTwo();
Batch.Products.forEach(batchProduct => {
    product = doneDataTwo.find(doneDataTwo => doneDataTwo.ProductId == batchProduct.ProductId);

    if (product) { 
        console.log(product);
    }
});
```

Or is there alternative better approach?

Demo:

```js
const Batch = {
  Products: [{ ProductId: 222 }, { ProductId: 666 }, { ProductId: 333 }]
};

function getDoneDataOne() {
    return { 
        '111': { Name: 'Item One', TotalDone: 3 },
        '222': { Name: 'Item Two', TotalDone: 3 },
        '333': { Name: 'Item Three', TotalDone: 1 } 
    }
}

function getDoneDataTwo() {
    return [
        { ProductId: 111, Name: 'Item One', TotalDone: 3 },
        { ProductId: 222, Name: 'Item Two', TotalDone: 3 },
        { ProductId: 333, Name: 'Item Three', TotalDone: 1 } 
    ]
}

// Example 1
const doneDataOne = getDoneDataOne();
Batch.Products.forEach(product => {
    batchProductId = product.ProductId;

    if (doneDataOne[batchProductId]) { //Is this correct way?
        console.log(doneDataOne[batchProductId]);
    }
});

// Example 2
const doneDataTwo = getDoneDataTwo();
Batch.Products.forEach(batchProduct => {
    product = doneDataTwo.find(doneDataTwo => doneDataTwo.ProductId == batchProduct.ProductId);

    if (product) { 
        console.log(product);
    }
});
```

Comment: First option definitely has lower complexity than second option. Don't `.find` when you can achieve the same thing with a plain property lookup instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends a lot what you're going to do with the resulting data.

If you know you're going to be accessing individual items by known ids, then it will be more convenient to use an object and use ids as keys eg `var item = data[id];` so that you don't have to loop over or filter an array to access the items.

If you need to sort the data for example, an array would facilitate that.

Without knowing exactly what you're doing with the data it's hard to say one is definitely better than the other, both have their place.